# Global rescue and logging exceptions in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, error-handling, sinatra

How do I specify a global rescue in case of an exception, and if you use Sinatra for an API or application, how do you handle logging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

404s can be handled with the help of the `not_found` method like eg:

```
not_found do
  'Site does not exist.'
end
```

500s can be handled by calling the error method with a block, eg:

```
error do
  "Application error. Pls try later."
end
```

The details of the error can be accessed via the `sinatra.error` in `request.env` like so:

```
error do
  'An error occured: ' + request.env['sinatra.error'].message
end
```

Comment: how do I do to retreive the exception if it's a 500, I mean what went wrong ? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had trouble getting this working out of the box in my dev environment - to get it to work, I had to set `show_exceptions` to false in my sinatra config.

```
class BaseApp < Sinatra::Base

  configure { set :show_exceptions, false }

  error do |err|
    raise "Error: #{err}"
  end

end
```

This setting, when set to true, enables error pages that show backtrace and environment information when an unhanded exception occurs, but I could only fire custom errors by disabling it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It doesn't work without the configure line.

Comment: Actually, both `:show_exceptions` and `:raise_errors` must be disabled (i.e., set to false) in order for the generic error block (i.e., no exception class or status code) to be executed and returned.

Comment: Note that `err` in the example is the message of the exception, which can also be obtained by `env['sinatra.error'].message`.

Comment: You can also `set :show_exceptions, :after_handler` in development, which will run your `error` blocks and then fall back to the default backtrace page.